# Recalcular rota com a API do Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou fazendo um aplicativo de monitoramento. Eu queria enviar um alerta na API do Google Maps Javascript quando o usuário mudar a rota ou que a rota fosse recalculada. Gostaria de saber como fazer o cálculo para a alteração de rota.

Obrigado.

Comment: Calcula se o KM atual foi alterado. Se sim, porquê mudou a rota.

Comment: Como está passando a rota para a API? Coloque seu código, e talvez possa te ajudar .

Comment: Se puder, comente o codigo que você está usando.